# jGroups jar giving Exception

Tags: java, jgroups

We have a legacy project and we are using jgroups-all 2.2.9.1 jar.
We are facing a issue from the past few days where our server crashes giving following

```
      exception :
      java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative
      at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.ring.UdpRingNode.receiveToken(UdpRingNode.java:59)
      at org.jgroups.protocols.TOTAL_TOKEN$TokenTransmitter.run(TOTAL_TOKEN.java:1116)
```

we think this is occuring due to the old jgroups jar we are using.but then if we upgrade the jar file there is another problem.The new jar has removed the sub package **ring**(org.jgroups.protocol.ring) from package **protocol**.

So my question is how should we proceed ?. if i will have to change the implementation of udpring then what should i use instead?.

Answer (score 0):

The exception tells the entire story :

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: timeout value is negative`

There must be a call to method that expects a positive value for its argument and you may be giving a negative value to it, so it throws an exception.

Imagine I am having a `java.util.Date` object, and then I call a method to set the year as

```
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
d.setYear(-123);
```

Then it may throw this kind of exception as I cannot specify negative value for year.

So just have check where your code is accessing the jar's code that throws this exception and make a check whether the parameter value passed are of correct value.